# Создание переменной с заданными именем и значением

Tags: matlab

Есть массивы `vector1` и `vector2`. В каждом, например, по 5 значений: символьные и численные соответственно.

Как создать ряд переменных (5 штук) с именем из `vector1` и значением из `vector2`?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ нашел сам, делюсь:

```
eval([vector1(1), ' = ', num2str(vector2(1))]);
```

или так:

```
assignin('base', [num2str(vactor1(1))], vector2(1));
```

Первый вариант "говорят" почему-то не использовать, почему не знаю. Ответ нашел тут: [English StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099398/create-variables-with-names-from-strings)